# AWS sites routed through Route 53 works on some networks, but not others

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, aws-amplify, aws-route53

I have a domain that is registered elsewhere, but is routed through NS to Route 53.
NS records are set correctly and using tool like whatsmydns.net returns correct NS records for most (however not all, some areas simply go to the red X instantly).

Inside the public hosted zone in Route 53, the domain routes an AWS Amplify through CNAME (this was done automatically by AWS, when using the connect domain interface in Amplify). It has passed more than a week since all of this was done, however there are still networks, where the DNS just doesn't resolve and returns an error.

DNESSEC is active, https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/ returns no errors.

I'll add a screenshot of Route 53 [dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwdoV.png).

Any ideas as how to resolve this ? I have never encountered an issue like this, especially since it works and DNS resolves correctly for me.

I have triple checked the NS records, they are set correctly. I tried deleting and creating the hosted zone from scratch again 2 weeks ago, it still doesn't/didn't work.

Comment: DNS combines the two hard problems in IT: Cache Invalidation and Naming things. Some resolvers don't honor the TTL of DNS records, there isn't much you can do beyond waiting - it appears to be set up correctly. It's good practice to lower the TTL a few days/weeks before you plan DNS changes to reduce the chance of this mess.